# Javascript prototypes - what's the advantage in this case?

Tags: javascript, prototype

"Oh no", I hear you groan, "not this question again", but bear with me for a minute.

I am trying to get to grips with prototyping and I understand the benefits of sharing common functionality across instances of an object.  However, in the following case what am I gaining by using a prototype instead of just a standalone function?

I want to take a sentence and randomise the positions of each word, so I can either do the following:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = function() {
var i = this.length;
if (i == 0) return this;
while (--i) {
    var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1 ));
    var a = this[i];
    var b = this[j];
    this[i] = b;
    this[j] = a;
}

    return this;
};

function randomiser(){
    var s = "My name is Bob";
    var shuffledSentence = s.split(' ').shuffle().join(' ');
    console.log(shuffledSentence); // "Bob My name is"

}
```

or, I can use a simple function call instead to randomise my string:

```
function randomise(arrayToRandomise){
    var i = arrayToRandomise.length;
    if (i == 0) return arrayToRandomise;
    while (--i) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1 ));
        var a = arrayToRandomise[i];
        var b = arrayToRandomise[j];
        arrayToRandomise[i] = b;
        arrayToRandomise[j] = a;
    }

    return arrayToRandomise;
}

 function randomiser(){
    var s = "My name is Bob";
    var shuffledSentence = s.split(' ');//.shuffle().join(' ');
    var myShuffledString = this.randomise(shuffledSentence).join(' ');
    console.log(myShuffledString);  // "Bob My name is"
}
```

What am I gaining here by using a prototype (apart from more elegant code!)?

Comment: Personally I stay away from changing native object's prototype as it can break `for .. in` and apparently it breaks encapsulation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice.3A_Extension_of_native_prototypes Using prototypes in your own defined objects makes it possible to use known patterns for inheritance, code re use and so on (OOP standard patterns): http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference or any pros or cons to distinguish between them, I go with the second solution, because we better not modify the JavaScript native prototypes, unless (the only case that I would agree on modifying native prototypes) to cover some cross-browser issues. for instance, if your browser doesn't support **forEach** in Array, as you might need it in your code, IMHO, it is not a bad thing to add it to your Array.prototype.

But the point is the better way to do that is code this in a way that doesn't affect anything, like when you change the `Array.prototype` like this:

```
Array.prototype.shuffle = ...
```

then if you iterate the array with `for(..in)`, your shuffle would show up.

So if I were you and I wanted to modify a native prototype, I would do that like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "shuffle", {
    enumerable:false,
    value:function(){
        //your code
    }
});
```

this way, using the enumerable property, you can prevent it from showing up in `for(..in)` loops or `Object.keys()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have that much to say about this, but IMHO here are some points:

- `prototype` should best not be extended to native objects, this is somewhat akin to polluting the global namespace, but that's somewhat a matter of opinion.
- `prototype` is really just a construct for OO, which philosophically just makes code more elegant, so in this case I think that's all prototype does here.